# Explanation on Series (Divergence Test) [ Solved]

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergence-operator

So, I'm a bit baffle on this concept for the convergence of series.

Test for Divergence: [http://imgur.com/XZk547T](https://imgur.com/XZk547T) (2/5)≠0 So, it's divergent.

Now, let's take a look at this example: [http://imgur.com/EWYc8Dk](https://imgur.com/EWYc8Dk)

For this example, it converges to -(8/7). What? Did I miss something? I thought it had to be zero in order to converge?

Comment: $s_n$ denotes the sequence of partial sums, i.e. $\displaystyle s_n:=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k$. The divergence test deals with $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k$

Answer (score 3):

Every series has two sequences associated with it.

If our series is $S = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n$, then the two sequences are:

- $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots$.  This is the sequence of the terms of the series.
- $S_1, S_2, S_3, \dots$.  This is the sequence of partial sums of the series.  We define these as $S_k = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^k a_n$.  For example, $S_3 = a_1 + a_2 + a_3$.

> I thought it had to be zero in order to converge

The limit *of the sequence* must be zero.  In other words, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n = 0$ must be true.

The *series* itself could potentially take on any value.  In other words, $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to+\infty} S_n$ is not necessarily zero since a series could converge to a nonzero number.

For example, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \sin n$ diverges, because $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to+\infty} \sin n$ does not exist (and therefore is not zero).

Another example is $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac1{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}6$.

**WARNING:**  The limit of the sequence being zero is not a sufficient condition for convergence.  For example, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac1n$ diverges even though $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac1n = 0$.

Comment: It's starting to make much more sense, but there's something stopping me from completely comprehending it. The weird thing is that I don't have an issue with other problems that involve n!, n^n, b^n (b>1), etc. It's only problems that have polynomials on top and the bottom with equal powers. I'm just too fixated with the idea of limits being able to approach a number and that number being the number it convergences to (every single time).

Comment: @Mathematicu5 if that's the case then I think you'll get the hang of it with a bit more practice.  Just keep in mind that there are two sequences associated with every series.  Also if the sequence $a_n$ truly is a rational function of $n$ (polynomial on top and polynomial on bottom, nothing else "non-polynomial" like $\sqrt n$ or $\cos n$, etc.) and if the degrees of the numerator and denominator are the same, then the series $\sum_n a_n$ will always diverge because $\lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n$ can never be zero in this case.

Comment: Thank You! Honestly, you just beat the crap of that voice in my head that wasn't allowing me to comprehend this. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of convergence of a series:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges if $L=\lim_{N\to\infty}s_N=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N a_n$ exists.

It then follows that if $\lim_{N\to\infty}s_N$ exists, then

$\lim_{N\to\infty}a_N=\lim_{N\to\infty}s_N-s_{N-1}=L-L=0$

Thus, for a series to converge, each individual term must approach zero.

However, the converse is not true.  Just because each term goes to zero does not mean the series will converge.

Comment: Just $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$, not $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$.

Comment: @tilper Oops, thanks for the catch, I fixed it.